# Raycaster displays phantom perpendicular wall faces

Tags: haskell, html5-canvas, raycasting, haste

The output looks like this:

[image]

You should just see a flat, continuous red wall on one side, blue wall on another, green on another, yellow on another (see the definition of the map, `testMapTiles`, it's just a map with four walls). Yet there are these phantom wall faces of varying height, which are perpendicular to the real walls. Why?

Note that the white "gaps" aren't actually gaps: it's trying to draw a wall of height `Infinity` (distance 0). If you specifically account for it (this version of the code doesn't) and just cap it at screen height, then you just see a very high wall there.

The source code is below. It's plain Haskell, using [Haste](http://haste-lang.org/) to compile to JavaScript and render to canvas. It is based on the C++ code from [this tutorial](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html#Untextured_Raycaster_), though note that I replaced `mapX` and `mapY` with `tileX` and `tileY`, and I don't have the `ray` prefix for `pos` and `dir` within the main loop. Any discrepancies from the C++ code are probably what's breaking everything, but I can't seem to find any after having pored over this code many times.

Any help?

```
import Data.Array.IArray
import Control.Arrow (first, second)

import Control.Monad (forM_)

import Haste
import Haste.Graphics.Canvas

data MapTile = Empty | RedWall | BlueWall | GreenWall | YellowWall deriving (Eq)

type TilemapArray = Array (Int, Int) MapTile

emptyTilemapArray :: (Int, Int) -> TilemapArray
emptyTilemapArray dim@(w, h) = listArray ((1, 1), dim) $ replicate (w * h) Empty

testMapTiles :: TilemapArray
testMapTiles =
    let arr = emptyTilemapArray (16, 16)
        myBounds@((xB, yB), (w, h)) = bounds arr
    in  listArray myBounds $ flip map (indices arr) (\(x, y) ->
            if x == xB then RedWall
            else if y == yB then BlueWall
            else if x == w then GreenWall
            else if y == h then YellowWall
            else Empty)

type Vec2 a = (a, a)
type DblVec2 = Vec2 Double
type IntVec2 = Vec2 Int

add :: (Num a) => Vec2 a -> Vec2 a -> Vec2 a
add (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)

mul :: (Num a) => Vec2 a -> a -> Vec2 a
mul (x, y) factor = (x * factor, y * factor)

rot :: (Floating a) => Vec2 a -> a -> Vec2 a
rot (x, y) angle =
    (x * (cos angle) - y * (sin angle), x * (sin angle) + y * (cos angle))

dbl :: Int -> Double
dbl = fromIntegral

-- fractional part of a float
-- `truncate` matches behaviour of C++'s int()
frac :: Double -> Double
frac d = d - dbl (truncate d)

-- get whole and fractional parts of a float
split :: Double -> (Int, Double)
split d = (truncate d, frac d)

-- stops 'Warning: Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type ‘Integer’'
square :: Double -> Double
square = (^ (2 :: Int))

-- raycasting algorithm based on code here:
-- http://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html#Untextured_Raycaster_

data HitSide = NorthSouth | EastWest deriving (Show)

-- direction, tile, distance
type HitInfo = (HitSide, IntVec2, Double)

-- pos: start position
-- dir: initial direction
-- plane: camera "plane" (a line, really, perpendicular to the direction)
traceRays :: TilemapArray -> Int -> DblVec2 -> DblVec2 -> DblVec2 -> [HitInfo]
traceRays arr numRays pos dir plane = 
    flip map [0..numRays] $ \x -> 
        let cameraX = 2 * ((dbl x) / (dbl numRays)) - 1
        in  traceRay arr pos $ dir `add` (plane `mul` cameraX)

traceRay :: TilemapArray -> DblVec2 -> DblVec2 -> HitInfo
traceRay arr pos@(posX, posY) dir@(dirX, dirY) =
    -- map tile we're in (whole part of position)
    -- position within map tile (fractional part of position)
    let ((tileX, fracX), (tileY, fracY)) = (split posX, split posY)
        tile = (tileX, tileY)
    -- length of ray from one x or y-side to next x or y-side
        deltaDistX = sqrt $ 1 + (square dirY / square dirX)
        deltaDistY = sqrt $ 1 + (square dirX / square dirY)
        deltaDist  = (deltaDistX, deltaDistY)
    -- direction of step
        stepX = if dirX < 0 then -1 else 1
        stepY = if dirY < 0 then -1 else 1
        step  = (stepX, stepY)
    -- length of ray from current position to next x or y-side
        sideDistX = deltaDistX * if dirX < 0 then fracX else 1 - fracX
        sideDistY = deltaDistY * if dirY < 0 then fracY else 1 - fracY
        sideDist  = (sideDistX, sideDistY)
        (hitSide, wallTile) = traceRayInner arr step deltaDist tile sideDist
    in  (hitSide, wallTile, calculateDistance hitSide pos dir wallTile step)

traceRayInner :: TilemapArray -> IntVec2 -> DblVec2 -> IntVec2 -> DblVec2 -> (HitSide, IntVec2)
traceRayInner arr step@(stepX, stepY) deltaDist@(deltaDistX, deltaDistY) tile sideDist@(sideDistX, sideDistY)
    -- a wall has been hit, report hit direction and coördinates
    | arr ! tile /= Empty   = (hitSide, tile)
    -- advance until a wall is hit
    | otherwise             = case hitSide of
        EastWest ->
            let newSideDist = first (deltaDistX+) sideDist
                newTile     = first (stepX+) tile
            in
                traceRayInner arr step deltaDist newTile newSideDist
        NorthSouth ->
            let newSideDist = second (deltaDistY+) sideDist
                newTile     = second (stepY+) tile
            in
                traceRayInner arr step deltaDist newTile newSideDist
    where
        hitSide = if sideDistX < sideDistY then EastWest else NorthSouth

-- calculate distance projected on camera direction
-- (an oblique distance would give a fisheye effect)
calculateDistance :: HitSide -> DblVec2 -> DblVec2 -> IntVec2 -> IntVec2 -> Double
calculateDistance EastWest (startX, _) (dirX, _) (tileX, _) (stepX, _) =
    ((dbl tileX) - startX + (1 - dbl stepX) / 2) / dirX
calculateDistance NorthSouth (_, startY) (_, dirY) (_, tileY) (_, stepY) =
    ((dbl tileY) - startY + (1 - dbl stepY) / 2) / dirY

-- calculate the height of the vertical line on-screen based on the distance
calculateHeight :: Double -> Double -> Double
calculateHeight screenHeight 0 = screenHeight
calculateHeight screenHeight perpWallDist = screenHeight / perpWallDist

width   :: Double
height  :: Double
(width, height) = (640, 480)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    cvElem <- newElem "canvas" `with` [
            attr "width" =: show width,
            attr "height" =: show height
        ]
    addChild cvElem documentBody
    Just canvas <- getCanvas cvElem
    let pos     = (8, 8)
        dir     = (-1, 0)
        plane   = (0, 0.66)
    renderGame canvas pos dir plane

renderGame :: Canvas -> DblVec2 -> DblVec2 -> DblVec2 -> IO ()
renderGame canvas pos dir plane = do
    let rays    = traceRays testMapTiles (floor width) pos dir plane
    render canvas $ forM_ (zip [0..width - 1] rays) (\(x, (side, tile, dist)) ->
        let lineHeight  = calculateHeight height dist
            wallColor   = case testMapTiles ! tile of
                RedWall     -> RGB 255 0 0
                BlueWall    -> RGB 0 255 0
                GreenWall   -> RGB 0 0 255
                YellowWall  -> RGB 255 255 0
                _           -> RGB 255 255 255
            shadedWallColor = case side of
                EastWest    -> 
                    let (RGB r g b) = wallColor
                    in  RGB (r `div` 2) (g `div` 2) (b `div` 2)
                NorthSouth  -> wallColor
        in  color shadedWallColor $ do
                translate (x, height / 2) $ stroke $ do
                    line (0, -lineHeight / 2) (0, lineHeight / 2))
    -- 25fps
    let fps             = 25
        timeout         = (1000 `div` fps) :: Int
        rots_per_min    = 1
        rots_per_sec    = dbl rots_per_min / 60
        rots_per_frame  = rots_per_sec / dbl fps
        tau             = 2 * pi
        increment       = tau * rots_per_frame 

    setTimeout timeout $ do
       renderGame canvas pos (rot dir $ -increment) (rot plane $ -increment)
```

HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Raycaster</title>

<noscript>If you're seeing this message, either your browser doesn't support JavaScript, or it is disabled for some reason. This game requires JavaScript to play, so you'll need to make sure you're using a browser which supports it, and enable it, to play.</noscript>
<script src=raycast.js></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "phantom faces" are occurring because an incorrect `HitSide` is being reported: you're saying the face was hit on a horizontal move (`EastWest`), but was actually hit on a vertical move (`NorthSouth`), or vice-versa.

Why is it reporting an incorrect value, then? `if sideDistX < sideDistY then EastWest else NorthSouth` seems pretty foolproof, right? And it is.

The problem isn't how we calculated that value. It's *when* we calculated that value. The distance calculation function needs to know the direction we moved in to get to the wall. However, what we've actually given is the direction we would move in if we were to keep going (that is, if that tile wasn't a wall, or we were to ignore it for some reason).

Look at the Haskell code:

```
traceRayInner arr step@(stepX, stepY) deltaDist@(deltaDistX, deltaDistY) tile sideDist@(sideDistX, sideDistY)
    -- a wall has been hit, report hit direction and coördinates
    | arr ! tile /= Empty   = (hitSide, tile)
    -- advance until a wall is hit
    | otherwise             = case hitSide of
        EastWest ->
            let newSideDist = first (deltaDistX+) sideDist
                newTile     = first (stepX+) tile
            in
                traceRayInner arr step deltaDist newTile newSideDist
        NorthSouth ->
            let newSideDist = second (deltaDistY+) sideDist
                newTile     = second (stepY+) tile
            in
                traceRayInner arr step deltaDist newTile newSideDist
    where
        hitSide = if sideDistX < sideDistY then EastWest else NorthSouth
```

Notice that we do things in this order:

1. calculate `hitSide`
2. check if a wall has been hit, and if so, report `hitSide`
3. move

Compare this to the original C++ code:

```
//perform DDA
while (hit == 0)
{
  //jump to next map square, OR in x-direction, OR in y-direction
  if (sideDistX < sideDistY)
  {
    sideDistX += deltaDistX;
    mapX += stepX;
    side = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    sideDistY += deltaDistY;
    mapY += stepY;
    side = 1;
  }
  //Check if ray has hit a wall
  if (worldMap[mapX][mapY] > 0) hit = 1;
}
```

It does things in a different order:

1. check if a wall has been hit, and if so, report `side` (equivalent to `hitSide`)
2. move and calculate `side`

The C++ code only calculates `side` when it moves, and then it reports that value if it hits a wall. So, it reports the way it moved in order to hit the wall.

The Haskell code calculates `side` whether or not it moves: so it's correct for each move, but when it hits a wall, it reports the way it would have moved were it to keep going.

So, the Haskell code can be fixed by re-ordering it so that it checks for a hit *after* moving, and if so, reports the `hitSide` value from that move. This isn't pretty code, but it works:

```
traceRayInner arr step@(stepX, stepY) deltaDist@(deltaDistX, deltaDistY) tile sideDist@(sideDistX, sideDistY) =
    let hitSide = if sideDistX < sideDistY then EastWest else NorthSouth
    in  case hitSide of
        EastWest ->
            let newSideDist = first (deltaDistX+) sideDist
                newTile     = first (stepX+) tile
            in  case arr ! newTile of
                -- advance until a wall is hit
                Empty   ->  traceRayInner arr step deltaDist newTile newSideDist
                -- a wall has been hit, report hit direction and coördinates
                _       ->  (hitSide, newTile)
        NorthSouth ->
            let newSideDist = second (deltaDistY+) sideDist
                newTile     = second (stepY+) tile
            in  case arr ! newTile of
                -- advance until a wall is hit
                Empty   ->  traceRayInner arr step deltaDist newTile newSideDist
                -- a wall has been hit, report hit direction and coördinates
                _       ->  (hitSide, newTile)
```

Problem solved!

---

Side note: I figured out what was wrong after carrying out the algorithm on paper. While in that particular case it just so happened the last two `HitSide` values matched, it became obvious that that they might not in every case. So, a big thanks to `Madsy` on Freenode's `#algorithms` for suggesting trying it out on paper. :)

Comment: @K3N I know. You have to wait a while before accepting any answer though, even your own.

Comment: heh I remember I got the same problem in the past due to 2 reasons one was if player was on a cell boundary and the other was the same as you ... I ended up with a small translation of the ray in the first case and the other is solved by z sorting each two horizontal and vertical hits ... see [Ray Casting with different height size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251071/2521214)