# Translating a y-shearing horizon offset to a pitch angle in a raycaster

Tags: graphics, 3d, trigonometry, projection, raycasting

I am writing a first-person shooter, using raycasting to render the world. I have added y-shearing successfully, so that I can look up and down (albeit with a bit of warping, as expected). If my y-pitch value is zero, the horizon line (indicated by the the thin red line) is in the center of the screen.

[image: center]

If I am looking completely down, my y-pitch value equals -half_screen_height, because that offset is added to the horizon line. You can see the same thin horizon line near the top.

[image: down]

For looking completely up, the inverse applies.
Now, the problem which I'm facing is that I want to incorporate vertical aiming to target enemies at heights higher than zero, like this one:

[image]

I am able to trace a 2D projectile because I have the view angle of the player, and from there I can step a certain X and Y amount in a loop, so that `x += cos(theta) * step` and `y += sin(theta) * step`. That is fairly easy. But in order to trace in a 3rd dimension, I need another angle that tells me how much I am looking upwards or downwards. Does anyone have an idea on how I can translate a y-pitch horizon line offset to an angle?

Edit: just to clarify, a commenter said that this is an altitude change, which is not true. Below is a GIF that demonstrates the difference between y-shearing (shown first) and changing the player height (shown second). For a given y-pitch value, it is added to each wall column's y position on screen, thus moving it upwards; but that is not an altitude change.

[image: shear vs altitude change]

Note: the GIF is very compressed because of stackoverflow's 2mb size limit.

Comment: The shearing is not a tilt but changing altitude instead (see the jumping GIF at the end in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251071/2521214) ). So you might shoot your projectiles from different altitude (but still not tilted) so no need for angle just add the altitude. If you tilt the projectile trajectory I am afraid it would look weird. If you still want to do it then the angle would be `tilt = atan(shear/d)` where `d` is some constant perpendicular distance you are aiming at. If you have a laser dot then its the distance to the hitted wall, If not then use `d` as something fixed.

Comment: @Spektre See my updated post; this is not an altitude change. I know it would look a bit weird with the stretch from the shearing, but I am okay with that. I have already added altitude changing in my engine, and that is also be a way in which you can hit enemies, as the projectile ray currently accounts for if the bullet position lands in a raised tile or not.

Comment: @Spektre For the constant perpendicular distance, I used the distance to the projection plane, which I define as `half_screen_w / tan(fov / 2.0)`. Your formula seems to produce correct angles, which is amazing! Can you explain how it works?

Comment: I created answer with some description how it works but its basic goniometric math. Your GIF shows me its really a tilt :) how it works? You are casting ray per pixel or per column of screen? if per column how are you distorting the floor/ceiling? How are you differentiating between altitude and tilt?

Comment: btw you can use 16 colors GIFs with dithering and lower framerate ... that will shrink the size considerably. I often hit the 2MB limit too ...

Comment: @Spektre I am differentiating between the two like this: for a tilt value of N (equivalent to the y-pitch above), I add N to the screen y-coordinate of every object in the scene, thus shifting walls + billboard sprites up or down. Here is how I am doing altitude changes: if my height is 1.5, I am standing above 1.5 blocks (same unit system as in 2D). Not accounting for multi-height walls (as that becomes more complicated), for a given wall column, the y-coordinate of the top equals `horizon_line - half_wall_height + player_height * wall_height`.

Comment: Got it tilt is applied before projection and altitude after ...

Comment: @Spektre Also, I am casting one ray per column of the screen; that ray travels until it hits the highest possible tile height or it is out of map to traverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it like this:

[image: triangle]

So your aim forms a right angle triangle along with shear and some predefined perpendicular distance (or distance to target) so:

```
tan(tilt) =      shear/d
    tilt  = atan(shear/d)
```

The `shear` is signed so the `tilt` will be also signed...

The idea is that ratio of sides in right angle triangle will give you `tan` or `ctg` (which depends on which of the 2 angles and on order of the sides in ratio). And `atan,actg` are inverse functions to `tan,ctg` so applying it on the ratio or `tan` will get the original tilt angle...

You empiricaly determined:

```
d=half_screen_w/tan(fov/2.0)
```

So its like end of the gun is near projection plane.