# Ray bouncing: How to invert a velocity vector to represent a perfect bounce?

Tags: javascript, math, vector, game-engine, raytracing

I'm working on a voxel raytracing system in JavaScript, which odd as it may sound is quite doable in a simple form. I'm trying to figure out how to make a virtual ray bounce and can't quite wrap my mind around the algorithm.

The concept is simple: Each ray is a virtual point with two properties, a position and a velocity, both stored as an `x, y, z` vector which is a dictionary. Each tick the velocity is added to the position, voxels at the new point are also searched at that point. The relevant part is something among the lines of:

```
for(let step = 0; step < dist_max; step++) {
    pos.x += vel.x;
    pos.y += vel.y;
    pos.z += vel.z;
    if(solid_at(pos)) {
        // A voxel was hit
    }
}
```

When a successful hit occurs, I need to do something to `vel` to reverse the direction of the ray and make it bounce like a rubber ball. Without making it lose or gain speed just change its direction. The surface can be considered to have no angle so no need to take any collider properties into account, it only needs to bounce as if it hits a flat plane facing right toward the ray... it would be useful if an amount between 0 and 1 can control how much the effect is applied so semi-transparent voxels may reflect / refract accordingly.

Clearly the secret isn't to multiply all of the velocity by `-1` as that would only make it go backwards: I think I need to invert just one or two of its axes, or swap the velocity of one axis with that of another. But how do I know which should be flipped when the ray could be going in any direction and have any amount of velocity in either X and Y and Z both positive or negative?

Comment: I think you still need the `Collision` info to get the normal of the hit surface to determine which direction it should bounce. If that's not possible, consider simlutating all 3 possible bounces (reverse `x`, `y` or `z` direction individually) with a smaller velocity from the hit point. Which side gets out of the voxel first could be the axis you want to reverse. But it might not be 100% reliable if the hit point is too close to an edge of the voxel or the `vel` is too large.

Comment: In the experiment I'm working on, voxels are points without any mesh or shape, not even cubes... they're represented as just a color at a point in space. As such they have no geometry information of any sort. Scanning neighboring voxels would likely be too costly for a system I'm trying hard to keep optimal. Since I don't need great accuracy, I'm fine with simulating a simple "prefect bounce" meaning it merely reverses course while maintaining speed. The problem is knowing which direction the ray is predominantly coming from as to rotate the vector head-on around it.

Comment: What about right before hitting the voxel, you generate a temporary cube mesh using the same attributes of the voxel (if you do know which voxel is hit). After that use a ray cast from where the point before it hits to that cube using the same direction, and then get its ray collision info?

Comment: My system doesn't have a concept of meshes, I'm trying to keep it point only. I don't need that level of accuracy though: The ray can always act as if it hit a plane that was facing right toward it. I just need to grasp the basic transform vector for rotating the direction of the ray accordingly.

Comment: you need the plane (normal vector) and just reflect your "speed" vector around it so you should know which side of the voxel was hit and then just its normal ... just incrementing your position by speed vector is not good enough. [In 2D raycast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251071/2521214) you have to have 2 steps which are alternating see [2D image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJfQg.png) as you can see you can hit horizontal and vertical lines ...

Comment: I think in [3D raycast/raytrace](https://web.archive.org/web/20180618064202/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090782/how-to-best-write-a-voxel-engine-in-c-with-performance-in-mind/48092685#48092685) you need 3 alternating steps for this to make work

Comment: You actually have a "light particle" moving one step at a time? If you need to do this for every ray that's a lot of computations! How about instead calculating directly the point of intersection of the ray (given for instance as an initial, non-moving point, plus a direction vector) with the objects?

Comment: @Stef its not that hard calculation for 3D raster grid (Voxels) what you proposing is done for representations without spatial meaning (like "unordered" list of objects) where you need to test all objects. With Voxels you always known which object you hit as 3D position is also object index ...

Comment: @Spektre I don't really understand your comment. Even if you know which object you're going to hit, computing the point of intersection directly is always going to be more efficient (and much more precise, especially if everything is floating-point) than iteratively advancing a point step by step until it hits the object.

Comment: @Stef The reason I can get away with it is I designed the system for extremely low resolutions, both in terms of camera pixels and voxels: Main window is just 120 x 60 pixels @ FPS 30 refresh rate (`setInterval`) and a maximum draw distance of 8 steps, with a few other optimizations I got my test working at roughly 1/3 of one thread. It's possible I might port it to Python or Lua given I can't get proper multi-threading in JS and browser is pretty limited, for now the concept works but I'm stuck figuring out how to reflect rays only by making their velocity reflect itself.

Comment: @MirceaKitsune I am doing this in GLSL with much much better resolutions for both voxel grid and screen.... the empty space Stef is hinting is not always a thing (especially for voxel based renderers) but of coarse once sparce matrix, BVH and or more grids are merged together than yes first ray march and then ray trace ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this the simple way: Whenever a voxel is updated, the point checks its neighbors and stores new normals. Normals is a mere list of 6 boolean entries, representing if the space in that axis is empty for -X +X -Y +Y -Z +Z. The ray simply checks this dictionary and if a location is clear decides whether it can bounce in that direction or not. It can even flip the ray on multiple axes at once if it's a corner voxel.

```
if vel_x > 0 and mat.normals[0]:
    vel_x *= -1
elif vel_x < 0 and mat.normals[1]:
    vel_x *= -1
if vel_y > 0 and mat.normals[2]:
    vel_y *= -1
elif vel_y < 0 and mat.normals[3]:
    vel_y *= -1
if vel_z > 0 and mat.normals[4]:
    vel_z *= -1
elif vel_z < 0 and mat.normals[5]:
    vel_z *= -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with a simple but incomplete solution as a test: To make floors act as mirrors you can just use `+vel.x, -vel.y, +vel.z`. In my engine the Y axis is vertical whereas X and Z are horizontal positions: By flipping the ray horizontally you allow horizontal faces to act like a mirror.

[image]

Sadly this is a temporary victory and I'll be forced to revert it: This trick won't work on vertical walls. Since X and Z have their velocity unchanged they will simply pass right through the surface.

I'm thus left with the unrealistic solution of just sending the ray back toward the camera within a given angle error: Instead of a normal forward reflection you only see what's behind you, but at least using `-vel.x, -vel.y, -vel.z` works predictably from any angle and forms an image.

Let me know if anyone has any better ideas. My speed of light is 1, meaning the velocity vector will always have either -1 or +1 in at least one axis while the other two may have anything inside that range: I might be able to make it work everywhere by flipping across the axis of highest velocity, problem then is if the ray is suddenly going faster in the X direction rather than Z for example it will immediately snap to a different index of reflection.