# Raycasting in C with MiniLibX: Why is Texture Mirroring Correction Needed?

Tags: c, graphics

I'm working on a raycasting project using the MiniLibX library in C, similar to the style of classic FPS games like Wolfenstein 3D. I've encountered an issue with texture mirroring on certain walls, and I found a solution, but I'm not entirely sure why this solution works. I'm hoping to get a better understanding of the underlying problem.

Here's the relevant part of my raycasting function:

```
void raycast(g *g)
{
    // ... [other raycasting code] ...

    if (g->side == 0)
        g->wallX = g->posY + g->perpWallDist * g->rayDirY;
    else 
        g->wallX = g->posX + g->perpWallDist * g->rayDirX;
    g->wallX = g->wallX - (int)g->wallX;

    g->texX = (int)(g->wallX * (double)texWidth);
    if (g->side == 0 && g->rayDirX > 0)
        g->texX = texWidth - g->texX - 1;
    if (g->side == 1 && g->rayDirY < 0)
        g->texX = texWidth - g->texX - 1;

    // ... [rest of raycasting code] ...
}
```

I understand that g->texX is used to determine the x-coordinate on the texture for wall rendering. However, I'm not clear on why the texture mirroring correction (the last two if statements) is necessary.

Why do textures appear mirrored on certain walls without these corrections?
How exactly do these conditions `(g->side == 0 && g->rayDirX > 0 and g->side == 1 && g->rayDirY < 0)` determine when to apply the mirroring correction?

[image: example]

Comment: without the raycasting code is impossible to tell

Comment: https://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html codes are here

Comment: We generally expect questions to be self-contained here as external links may go away after the question has been answered.

Comment: no sure how `g->texX = (int)(g->wallX * (double)texWidth);` works as the texture coordinate should be derived from ray intersection point with wall so if `g->wallX` is the intersection point  I would expect to use just its fractional part (if its floating) like `g->wallX-floor(g->wallX)`  but if you handle your texture coordinates as repeating it could work (with risk of overflow on bigger maps) however I am missing the use of `g->wallY` in the same way you know you got horizontal and vertical walls (on map) so use x for one and y for the other ...

Comment: see [Ray Casting with different height size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251071/2521214) for some inspiration and crosscheck with working raycaster